# Different volume level for new email notification and new SMS notification?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, email, sms, audio, volume-control

I have lots of emails coming in all day. For this reason, my notification sounds level is low. But I need to be alarmed when I have a new SMS. Currently I don't always notice new SMS messages because they, too, have low volume level.

How would it be possible to have a different volume level for new email notification and new SMS notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple method would be to use a custom ringtone for SMS where the audio itself is louder.  You coould use a loud audio clip or edit one to be louder.

Comment: How would I extract existing notification sounds from Android to modify them in wave editor? I tried using USB connection to a computer but did't find Bubble, Rattlesnake etc in any of the folders.

Comment: That's probably a good candidate for a separate question.  I've never done it myself.

Answer (score 1):

[SMS Popup](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.everythingandroid.smspopup) lets you set custom notification sounds, volumes, vibrates, LED flash and icon for popups, separately from the system notification settings.

Well worth installing, it's the first app I put on my phones, and  the first I recommend to others, really fixes a hole in the Android notifications.

Comment: Can't see volume adjustments in SMS Popup.

Answer (score 0):

All of the more popular SMS replacement apps on Android - Handcent SMS, ChompSMS and GoSMS offer the ability to have custom ringtones. They also have customizable vibration patterns and you can also use custom notification icon colours and tones for a particular contact's SMS.

To adjust volume, however,  @Matthew's suggestion of different volume levels on ringtones is the easiest way to handle things.