# Turning off just email notification sound

Tags: notifications, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I turn off Notification Sounds and leave phone sounds on](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16149/how-can-i-turn-off-notification-sounds-and-leave-phone-sounds-on)

my dad just got a brand new Motorola XT603 running Android 2.3.5.  He would like to differ the notification sounds for emails/texts/voice mail but short of that, just turn off the sound for emails since he receives so many.  His email is NOT through gmail, but a work account.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would help to know what he's using as his mail program on the phone, what OS/Launcher he's running (if he's not using the OEM software) and how deeply those two are integrated. Hints; look through the mail app's settings for notification-related settings, and if that doesn't get you anywhere, look in the Notifications and/or Sounds section of the phone's main Settings; there may be a selection specifically for Mail that is used by his mail app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I turn off Notification Sounds and leave phone sounds on](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16149/how-can-i-turn-off-notification-sounds-and-leave-phone-sounds-on). See also: [How to turn off notifications for individual apps?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22708/) and [Different volume level for new email notification and new SMS notification?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6941/).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this probably is:

- get yourself an "empty" mp3 (i.e. one without any sound).
- on your device's SD card, create a folder named `media/audio/notifications` (if it's not already there).
- copy that "empty MP3" into this folder
- Now select this file as notification sound for new mail

So when the new mail notification sound is being played, you won't hear it anymore :)